# Do C# winforms have HtmlDecode() equivalent like Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

In the web using c# would be simple

```
 System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

but now I am using a winform application and need to convert Html escape values whats the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just reference the System.Web library and use it

Comment: And note that you'll have to switch away from the client profile in order to add a reference to System.Web.

Comment: damn, i didnt see it because the default client profile version of the .net framework was selected for this project. changed it to just plain .net4 and then it showed in the list of references.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `System.Web` to your project references, then you should be able to use the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a project reference to the `System.Web` dll and you should be able to use it.